# How to change an unknown numeric value with awk

Tags: awk, text-editing

I am new to learning `awk`.
I have a file that contains the following line, along with other lines:

```
TIMEOUT=200
```

I need to change the numeric value.
This command can change the value only if I know the value beforehand:

```
awk '$0 == "TIMEOUT=200" { sub ("200","5") } { print }' file
```

What command should I use if I don't know the value?
Something like this:

```
awk '$0 == "TIMEOUT=[0-9]" { sub ("[0-9]","5") } { print }' file
```

But I tried that command, and it doesn't change anything.

Answer (score 1):

- Your attempt doesn’t work because `==` tests only for exact equality. 
  If your file contained a line that said, exactly and literally,
  `TIMEOUT=[0-9]`, your code would recognize it
  (and change it to `TIMEOUT=[5-9]`). 
  But, as you’ve seen, it does not match strings like `TIMEOUT=42`. 
  You, of course, want to select lines
  that match the `TIMEOUT=number` pattern. 
  One way of doing that is to use the **`~`** operator instead of `==`:

  ```
  awk '$0 ~ "TIMEOUT=[0-9]" { action statement(s) }'
  ```
- It’s good to understand how to use the **`~`** operator,
  and to know that you can do tests on individual fields. 
  However,
  there’s a shorthand notation for matching the entire line against a pattern:

  ```
  awk '/TIMEOUT=[0-9]/      { action statement(s) }'
  ```

  and you might want to use that when you can.
- So now, if we do

  ```
  awk '/TIMEOUT=[0-9]/ { sub ("[0-9]","5") } { print }'
  ```

  it will match the `TIMEOUT=200` line — and change it to `TIMEOUT=500`,
  because `[0-9]` matches only a single digit (numeral),
  and not a multi-digit number. 
  To find (and substitute for) a multi-digit number
  (a string of one or more consecutive numerals),
  use the **`+`** character (operator),
  which means “one or more occurrences of the preceding pattern”,
  as in `sub ("[0-9]+","5")`.
- But I glossed over a problem earlier in this list. 
  While `==` tests for exact equality of the *complete* string,
  `~ "pattern"` and
  `/pattern/`
  test for a string containing a substring that matches the pattern. 
  So, for example, `/TIMEOUT=[0-9]/`
  will match a line that looks like

  ```
  In American football, a TIMEOUT=30seconds
  ```

  If that’s OK with you, fine. 
  I imagine you want to match only a complete line,
  so you will want to “anchor” the pattern
  so that `TIMEOUT` must be at the beginning of the line,
  and the number must be at the end. 
  You do this with the `^` and `$` characters,
  as in `/^TIMEOUT=[0-9]$/`.
  ***Except…***
- … as stated before, `[0-9]` matches only a single digit,
  so the above will match `TIMEOUT=7` but not `TIMEOUT=11`. 
  You need `/^TIMEOUT=[0-9]+$/`.

### TL;DR

You need
to do

```
awk '$0 ~ "^TIMEOUT=[0-9]+$" { sub ("[0-9]+","5") } { print }'  file
```

or

```
awk '/^TIMEOUT=[0-9]+$/      { sub ("[0-9]+","5") } { print }'  file
```

---

I encourage you to learn `awk`, as it can be very useful and very powerful. 
However, for a simple task like this,
you can get by with a simpler tool: `sed`.

Unfortunately,
`sed` normally doesn’t support the **`+`** (one or more) operator. 
In GNU `sed` (the version that comes with Cygwin
and most (if not all) Linux distributions),
you can specify the `-r` option
to tell it to recognize “extended regular expressions”. 
(Patterns like `[0-9]+` are called “regular expressions”.) 
So you could do

```
sed -r '/^TIMEOUT=[0-9]+$/s/[0-9]+/5/'
```

But some (older) versions of `sed` don’t honor the `-r` option
and don’t support extended regular expressions at all. 
Luckily, you can get around that:
there’s another special character (operator), **`*`**,
which means “*zero* or more occurrences of the preceding pattern”. 
“One or more digits” is equivalent to
“one digit, followed by zero or more additional digits,”
so we can translate `[0-9]+` to `[0-9][0-9]*`, and do the command as

```
sed '/^TIMEOUT=[0-9][0-9]*$/s/[0-9][0-9]*/5/'
```

Instead of `[0-9][0-9]*`, you can also do `[0-9]*[0-9]`
(one digit, *preceded* by zero or more additional digits). 
I prefer the second form, because I think it looks more balanced,
but it isn’t very popular.